# Are view() in Pytorch and reshape() in Numpy similar?

Tags: deep-learning, numpy, pytorch, reshape

Are `view()` in torch and `reshape()` in Numpy similar?

`view()` is applied on torch tensors to change their shape and `reshape()` is a numpy function to change shape of ndarrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for most intents and purposes, they can do the same job. From [this link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/equivalent-of-np-reshape-in-pytorch/144), an example:

```
>>> import torch
>>> t = torch.ones((2, 3, 4))
>>> t.size()
torch.Size([2, 3, 4])
>>> t.view(-1, 12).size()
torch.Size([2, 12])
```

---

If you are concerned with memory allocation, here is [another answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42479902/how-view-method-works-for-tensor-in-torch) with a little more information. PyTorch's `view` function actually does what the name suggests - [returns a *view*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42479902/how-view-method-works-for-tensor-in-torch) to the data. The data is not altered in memory as far as I can see.

In *numpy*, the [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape) function does not guarantee that a copy of the data is made or not. It will depend on the original shape of the array and the target shape. Have a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36995289/when-will-numpy-copy-the-array-when-using-reshape) for further information.